# mismatched #if/#endif pair in *.h file

Tags: visual-c++

Visual Studio C++ 2008

I have the following code in my server.h file.

```
#if defined ( __linux__ )
    void* get_info(void*);
#elif defined ( _WIN32)
    void* WINAPI get_info(void*)
#endif
```

I keep getting the error:

```
mismatched #if/#endif pair in server.h file
```

The code looks ok to me, I can't understand why I am getting this error?

Am I missing something?

Many thanks for any advice,

Comment: Could it be the missing semicolon after the function declaration after your `elif` text part?

Comment: Nope, wasn't the missing colon, that was were I was too quick to type into the question box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I asked this question.

I missed of the #endif at the end of the file for the header file define

i.e.

```
#ifndef SERVER_INCLUDED
#define SERVER_INCLUDED
.
.
.
#endif /* SERVER_INCLUDED */
```